# findViewById not recognized as a method within a SherlockFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment with two buttons inside. I cant attach the xml buttons to java buttons, because within the SherlockFragment Class, findViewById is not recognized as a method.

I changed SherlockFragment to SherlockFragmentActivity, but this way, the OnCreateView method is not the right one to be working with, and I dont know which method should I use instead?

**Variant 1: findViewById is not recognized as a method**

```
public class MyProfileActionButtonsFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    private Button bMyProfileEditProfile;
    private Button bMyProfileSettings;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_profile_action_buttons_fragment, container, false);

        bMyProfileEditProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMyProfileEditProfile);
        bMyProfileSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMyProfileSettings);

        bMyProfileEditProfile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent editUserProfile = new Intent (getActivity(), UserProfileEdit.class);
                startActivity(editUserProfile);

            }
        });
        bMyProfileSettings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent settings = new Intent (getActivity(), Settings.class);
                startActivity(settings);

            }
        });
    }
```

**Variant 2: The method onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) of type MyProfileActionButtonsFragment must override or implement a supertype method**

```
public class MyProfileActionButtonsFragment extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private Button bMyProfileEditProfile;
    private Button bMyProfileSettings;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_profile_action_buttons_fragment, container, false);

        bMyProfileEditProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMyProfileEditProfile);
        bMyProfileSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMyProfileSettings);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_profile_action_buttons_fragment, container, false);
bMyProfileEditProfile = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bMyProfileEditProfile);
bMyProfileSettings = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bMyProfileSettings);
bMyProfileEditProfile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent editUserProfile = new Intent (getActivity(), UserProfileEdit.class);
            startActivity(editUserProfile);
        }
    });
bMyProfileSettings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent settings = new Intent (getActivity(), Settings.class);
            startActivity(settings);
        }
    });
return view; 
}
```

Remove

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_profile_action_buttons_fragment, container, false);
```

`findViewById` is a method of activity class you need to use the inflated view object to initialize your buttons and you should return the inflated view.